# NO puedo ingresar a mi maquina LINUX AWS

Tags: aws, ssh, autenticación, ec2, putty

como estan? tengo un problema algo tonto aqui, pero no estoy pudiendo resolverlo.

tengo una instancia EC2 en AWS la misma está corriendo linux (redmine by bitnami) y no puedo ingresar a ella por medio de putty (ssh) como lo hacia normalmente usando la clave .ppk que tengo guardada

es raro porque ademas estuve ingresando usando usuario y clave que encuentro en el log del sistema y ahora no funciona

lo que hice para solucionarlo es, lanzar una instancia igual, tomar la nueva llave ppk provista e intentar loguearme, pero putty me muestra:

"No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)"

Comment: No es una pregunta de programación en sí, no creo que sea bien aceptada en este sitio, pero puedes preguntar en [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) en inglés.  suerte!

Comment: Gracias! en ingles se me dificulta un poco la verdad

Comment: usa [google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=es&tl=en&op=translate), tanto para escribir como para leer las respuestas, no cuesta tanto si escribes bien en castellano y te responden en ingles correcto :-)

Comment: Si no puedes conectarte usando la clave SSH ... mal asunto. Si conoces la contraseña asociada al usuario, puedes probar la consola serie. Vete a EC2, selecciona la instancia y en el menú "conectar" ve a la pestaña "consola de serie de EC2".

También puedes probar a reiniciar la instancia, a ver si es que se ha quedado algún proceso de SSH pillado.

Si no te funciona nada de esto, me temo que no vas a conseguir acceso a la instancia

Comment: gracias eferion, lo que mas raro me resulta es que lancé otra instancia similar y tampoco me dejó ingresar con la llave pem que generé

Comment: Estimados, ingreso a AWS, lanzo una instancia, genero y descargo la .ppk nueva para conectarme, y cuando la quiero utilizar en mi nueva instancia me dice ""No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)"